# how to retrieve the Nth-to-last element in a vector?

Tags: indexing, dolphindb

I have a question about DolphinDB:  how to retrieve the Nth-to-last element in a vector?

For example, I want to access the second-to-last element. In Python, I can use `v[-2]`. How can I do this in DolphinDB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also calculate the length of the vector and then use indexing to select the desired element.

```
len=v.size()  
v[(len-2):(len-1)]
```

or

`move` the vector to the right for 1 step, which will make the second-to-last element become the last one and then use the last function to  return it.

```
last(move(v, 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `tail` and `head` function

```
v.tail(2).head()
```